# spring mybatis transaction getting committed

Tags: spring, mybatis

I am trying to use mybatis spring transaction management
My problem is that the transactions are getting committed even if an exception is thrown.
Relatively new to this, anykind of help is much appreciated.
Following are the code snippets

spring xml configuration

```
 <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

        <property name="location">

            <value>classpath:Config.properties</value>

        </property>

    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
     <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${db.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${db.user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db.pass}"/>
    <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
    </bean>



     <bean id="transactionManager"      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>


  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:Configuration.xml" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate" id="sqlSessionTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="sqlSessionFactory"/>
   </bean>
```

Service class

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void insertNotes(String noteTypeId,String confidentialValue,String summaryValue,String notes ,String notesId,String noteTypeValue,
        String claimNumber,String notepadId,String mode)
{


        NotepadExample notepadExample= new NotepadExample();

        //to be moved into dao class marked with transaction boundaries
        Notepad notepad = new Notepad();
        notepad.setAddDate(new Date());
        notepad.setAddUser("DummyUser");
        if("true".equalsIgnoreCase(confidentialValue))
            confidentialValue="Y";
        else
            confidentialValue="N";
        notepad.setConfidentiality(confidentialValue);
        Long coverageId=getCoverageId(claimNumber);
        notepad.setCoverageId(coverageId);
        notepad.setDescription(summaryValue);

        notepad.setEditUser("DmyEditUsr");
        //notepad.setNotepadId(new Long(4)); //auto sequencing
        System.out.println(notes);
        notepad.setNotes(notes);
        notepad.setNoteType(noteTypeValue); //Do we really need this?
        notepad.setNoteTypeId(Long.parseLong(notesId));
        if("update".equalsIgnoreCase(mode))
        {
            notepad.setNotepadId(new Long(notepadId));
            notepad.setEditDate(new Date());
            notepadMapper.updateByPrimaryKeyWithBLOBs(notepad);

        }
        else
            notepadMapper.insertSelective(notepad);

              throw new java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException();





}
```

Not sure where I am going wrong...

The current call is from the controller as given below

```
 @Controller
public class NotesController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(NotesController.class);

    @Autowired
    private Utils utility;

    @Autowired
     NotepadService notepadService;


    public  @ResponseBody List<? extends Object> insertNotes(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,@RequestParam("noteTypeValue") String noteTypeId,
    @RequestParam("confidentialValue")String confidentialValue,
    @RequestParam("summaryValue")String summaryValue,
    @RequestParam("notes")String notes ,
    @RequestParam("notesId")String notesId,
    @RequestParam("noteTypeValue")String noteTypeValue,
    @RequestParam("claimNumber")String claimNumber,
    @RequestParam("notepadId")String notepadId,
    @RequestParam("mode")String mode) {

        try {
            notepadService.insertNotes(noteTypeId, confidentialValue, summaryValue, notes, notesId, noteTypeValue, claimNumber, notepadId, mode);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I am also relatively new to spring. But according to me it depends on how you are calling your insertNotes() method. If you are calling it from another local method then it will not work, because spring has no way of know that it is called and to start the transaction.

If you are calling it from a method of another class by using autowired object of the class which contains insertNotes() method, then it should work.

For example

```
class ABC
{
 @Autowired
 NotesClass notes;

   public void testMethod() {
      notes.insertNotes();
   }
}


class NotesClass
{
   @Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)  
   public void insertNotes(String noteTypeId,
                           String confidentialValue,
                           String summaryValue,String notes ,
                           String notesId,String noteTypeValue, 
                           String claimNumber,
                           String notepadId,
                           String mode) {
                //Your code
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, currently the way I am calling it is

Comment: Have updated the code with controller call to service.Doing it the same way I guess.

Comment: Did you use @Transactional in mapper or in serice layer?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using transaction template. Remove @Tranasactional annotation from method and following code to xml file.

```
 <bean id="trTemplate" class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
<property name="timeout" value="30"/>
<property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
</bean>
```

Create object of Trasactiontemplate and call insertNotes from controller like this

```
@Autowired
private TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {

        @Override
        protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus transactionStatus)  {


            try {
                insertNotes();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly();
                logger.error("Exception ocurred when calling insertNotes", e);  

                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    });
```

Note : You have to make all parameters final before calling insertNotes method